# coldfusion calculating HMAC256 of a getHTTPRequestData

Tags: java, coldfusion, shopify, hmac

I'm working with Shopify at the moment and using their webhook notifications so I can save stuff to our database.

Within their webhook headers, they provide a header of: `X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256`

which is:

> Each Webhook request includes a X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256 header which is generated using the app's shared secret (looks like: '267bb1719a8e6ff75c4f2d709be0ca11'), along with the data sent in the request.

This is jolly wonderful; However, I'm really struggling to calculate the value of the `X-Shopify-Hmac-Sha256`.

I have a `.cfm` page which the webhook hits and I pass through the `getHTTPRequestData` to a function like thus:

```
<cfscript>
variables.stArgs                        = {};
variables.stArgs.stWebHookData          = getHTTPRequestData();
application.stObj.stShopify.oShopifyWebHookBusiness.receiveWebHook(argumentCollection=variables.stArgs);
</cfscript>
```

I then stole some code from StackOverflow and Ben Nadel, but neither seem to end up giving me the value that I want.  Currently I'm using Ben Nadels code like thus:

```
local.data = arguments.stWebHookData.toString();
local.macClass = createObject( "java", "javax.crypto.Mac" );
local.secretkeySpec = createObject( "java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec" ).init(toBinary(toBase64(arguments.key)),'HmacSHA256');
local.mac = local.macClass.getInstance('HmacSHA256');
local.mac.init(local.secretkeySpec );

local.hashedBytes = local.mac.doFinal(toBinary(toBase64(local.data)));
return lcase( binaryEncode( local.hashedBytes, "base64" ) );
```

(`arguments.key` is the shared secret)

Somewhere along the way, I am going wrong.  Have I completely misunderstood what I am meant to be doing.  This looks so easy in PHP.

Comment: Did they provide a concrete example that you can match? You really need a sample to help you figure out if the problem is the hashing code OR the *data* you are hashing. (Usually the problem is the request data .. or how it is constructed.)

Comment: Oh how I wish they did.  They show how you can verify it in PHP and ruby, but they don't show the actual request that has been sent through.  I was trying to reverse engineer from PHP last night using phpfiddle but couldn't get it working using what I had stored from `getHTTPRequestData().toString()` and `ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content)` which might be wrong anyway.

Comment: Does `toBase64(local.mac.doFinal(getHTTPRequestData().content))` work? the content will likely be handled by CF as an array of bytes, which is what doFinal() expects

Comment: @barnyr please put that as the answer.  You just earned my respect and admiration.

Comment: @Jarede, very glad that worked! Seems there's no CF or Java examples out there, so hopefully this'll be of use to others too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, getHTTPRequestData() [returns a struct with a number of members](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_43.html). The one we're interested is content, which will be a byte array.

The MAC classes' [doFinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Mac.html#doFinal%28byte%5B%5D%29) method  expects an array of bytes (in our case the HTTP request's content) and returns an array of bytes (the HMac of the content)

The returned byte array needs to be base-64 encoded in order to compare it to the one Shopify puts in the webhook's headers. [toBase64()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_03.html) will do that for us.

Putting it all together, you get this:
`toBase64(local.mac.doFinal(getHTTPRequestData().content))`